# Why can't won't ecilpse connect to my Android device?

Tags: adb

I've done a bit of searching and found suggested solutions, but nothing works. When I try to run my Android program on my phone, I get this error:

```
2012-04-11 10:25:00 - Android Cheater Physics] Android Launch!
[2012-04-11 10:25:00 - Android Cheater Physics] Connection with adb was interrupted.
[2012-04-11 10:25:00 - Android Cheater Physics] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect.
[2012-04-11 10:25:00 - Android Cheater Physics] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

Restarting the adb gives me this error:

```
[2012-04-11 10:05:40 - ddms]Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
[2012-04-11 10:08:46 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-04-11 10:08:46 - Logcat]An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:395)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)

[2012-04-11 10:08:47 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2012-04-11 10:09:18 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I've tried unchecking and rechecking the debugger as well. I'm on a school computer and haven't had the chance to try it on my home computer. Although it worked before, perhaps the firewall is now blocking it or something? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried force-closing the adb service?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **DDMS** ,==> **Reset adb** ==> **restart** Eclipse

[image]