# HTC one just updated and now wont connect to DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, ddms, htcsense

I don't know why, but all my drivers are up to date and my HTC one won't connect.

Recently my HTC one updated and now when i connect it to my mac, i see it start charging. I even see the USB connection icon show up but DDMS and ADB both don't see the device.. I can't build to it from eclipse.

I checked the obvious, developer options usb debugging is on.. I HATE this phone by the way.. should have got the nexus 5.

anyone experience the same problem? have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I restarted the adb and my phone and it was able to pick it up

you could also try doing this: [Why can't won't ecilpse connect to my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110995/why-cant-wont-ecilpse-connect-to-my-android-device/19484818#19484818)